# Is it possible to display the input field below the header in the datatables?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am using the data tables. Is it possible to display the input field below the header?

I tried the below code but I am getting all the input fields in the single `tr`

Please check the screenshot
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
  $('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#example thead');

  var html = '<tr><th><input type="text" placeholder="Search Name" name="name"></th><th><input type="text" placeholder="Search Position" name="position"></th><th><input type="text" placeholder="Search Office" name="office"></th><th><input type="text" placeholder="Search Age" name="age"></th><th><input type="text" placeholder="Search Start date" name="date"></th><th><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></th></tr>';
  $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').append(html);

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    orderCellsTop: true,
    fixedHeader: true
  });

  $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    var data = table.$('input').serialize();
    alert("The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n");
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Bruce</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>2011/06/27</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>Customer Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/01/25</td>
        <td>$112,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are referring to the Search DOM element correct? Or you just want the input Name in the Name column, Position in Position... etc.?

Comment: @BeerusDev, Actually I am inserting the data using that form

Comment: Try `$('#example thead').append(html);`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc, Yes, It's working. Thanks for the help